# Jasmine. loop over beforeEach and it

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

I would like to run a loop over an array with a set of tests including  `beforeEach` setting up corresponding value, and `it` also using the values from the array.

The example below shows the general structure. The problem is `myArray` is not recognized when calling `forEach` on it (see the line with comment)

```
let myArray;
beforeAll(() => {
  myArray = getArray();
  log(myArray) // I can see its defined here
});
myArray.forEach((myValue) => { // myArray has no value here!!!
 beforeEach(function() {
  // do something with myValue
  log(myArray) // I can see its defined here
 });

 it('my test', () => {
   // do something with myValue
   log(myArray) // I can see its defined here
 });

}); // close loop
```

There are examples like [this](https://tosbourn.com/using-loops-in-jasmine/) to loop over `it`, but that doesn't address the scope of the values being looped over

Comment: Is the result of `getArray()` also undefined?

Comment: **Change** `let myArray;` **to** `var myArray`

Comment: @Phix I updated to code to show where `myArray` is defined

Comment: Cool - now **Change** let myArray; **to** var myArray

Comment: That wouldn't matter, @RandyCasburn.

Comment: @Phix - I saw the closure and thought "wrong context". Anyway, The code above is missing the closing `)` for the `beforAll()` right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `beforeAll` to get data for your array.
You could get data for tests in advance before you define test suite.

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3]; //get data for tests

describe('Name of the group', () => {

    myArray.forEach(element => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            console.log('Data set before each: ' + myArray)
        });

        it('My Test', () => {
            console.log('Test#' + element)
        });
    });
});
```

Possible to use data driven approach using [jasmine-data-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider)

```
const using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

let myArray = [1, 2, 3]; //get data for tests

describe('Name of the group using "using"', () => {       
    using(myArray, element => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            console.log('Data set before each: ' + myArray)
        });

        it('My Test', () => {
            console.log('Test#' + element)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, your `myArray` is hard-coded here, wondering if it is possible to inject it from another it function?

Comment: @zygimantus what would you like to accomplish? I would not recommend building or "getting" array from another `it` function as it would make your test depends on another and it is not great approach. Please let me know if you still have questions

Comment: Well, basically, I would like to read a set of data (metadata of tables) and for each element of data (a table) do a test - etc., check if data is in that table over a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `myArray.forEach` in one of the `beforeEach, it, afterEach, or afterAll`, as `beforeAll` is running asynchronously.

Comment: I understand how this is one way to work around the problem. However, I would like to run the beforeEach, then it for each value in myArray. In fact I have few different it tests I have to run in each cycle. If there was just one, I would have brought the beforeEach code into the it function. But in my case I would have to duplicate it in every one of the it functions.

Comment: @RonHarlev What if you put `myArray.forEach` into `beforeAll`?